# When to create Unit tests for routes in asp.net MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

It make sense to create unit tests for the routes in an asp.net mvc project if we don’t use our services and models like a restfull api?
I’m exploring a project that uses the MvcRouteUnitTester ([url for the project](https://mvcrouteunittester.codeplex.com/)) and has code like this:

```
using MvcRouteUnitTester;

[TestClass]
public class RouteTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIncomingRoutes()
    {
        var tester = new RouteTester<MvcApplication>();

        tester.WithIncomingRequest("/Foo").ShouldMatchRoute("Foo", "Index");
    }
}
```

If I always use the helper Url.Action to create links to my foo model, it still makes sense to create this unit tests?

Comment: Once you have had to debug a sudden failure in your application because a route ended up in a controller that wasn't intended to handle it, you know that you _do_ want to test your routes. It's much easier to catch inadvertent errors creeping in by route-tests starting to fail than it is to debug the situation from a live scenario where the only thing you know is "/whatever" isn't working (or producing strange results).

Comment: But If I always use the method Url.Action to construct the HTML links, how could a controller will be handle the wrong route? The Url.Action method receive a controller name and a action name and returns the HTML link to that controller action. Testing the routes, as I show bellow,  it is not just testing this Url.Action method? And If this method is in some API, maybe the testing responsibility is for the API maintainers and not mine.

Comment: If you can guarantee that nobody will ever construct an url manually..., then maybe. Not every coder may follow your example. And the fact that you provide the urls doesn't mean no visitor will ever construct one.  So you should at least test that wrong, invalid, no longer in use or unauthorised request urls end up in the correct place.